# js-cookie samesite and httpOnly

Tags: cookies

I'm using js-cookie 2.2.0 and I would like to add the `samesite` flag but i don't find anything about.

Here my actual code.

```
Cookies.set('traffweb' + cookieName, cookieStr, {
  expires: 7,
  path: window.location.href,
  secure: true
})
```

how can I add a `samesite` flag?

Comment: I am using js-cookie 2.2.1 and receiving deprecation warnings about "SameSite=None". In the 2.2.1 docs (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#samesite), 'sameSite' is mentioned, with possible values of 'strict' and 'lax', neither of which is defined. The default, if sameSite is not specified is "include cookie in any request". I am guessing that that was meant to say that the default is 'lax', and that 'strict' means "prevents the browser from sending cookie along with cross-site requests". Actual definitions in the docs would be helpful.

Comment: Once I added sameSite='strict' to my js_cookie Cookies call, nothing at all changed and I still receive the warning. That's why I'm not posting this as an answer. I have experimented with different casings, but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: The docs I was reading were for the 'master' branch. The 2.2.1 release docs do not mention sameSite, which would seem to explain why it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6):

I added a "sameSite" attribute and the warning went away

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { sameSite:'strict' });
```

Comment: how do i add None along with secure? Something like this? 

`Cookies.set('name', 'value', { SameSite: 'None; Secure' });` ?

Answer (score 6):

For SameSite=None + Secure:

```
    Cookies.set('name', 'value', {sameSite: 'None', secure: true});
```

Comment: thank you - just the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, "sameSite" is intended to be added in a future release of js-cookie, beyond 2.2.1. It is mentioned in the docs for the master branch of js-cookie on GitHub (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/latest#readme).

Whether this represents an actual code change or just a documentation update, I don't know. Setting sameSite='strict' did not eliminate the warning that I have been receiving. My own app does not need to pass cookies cross-site, so I am just ignoring the warning for now.

The answer, then, would seem to be to wait for a future version, assuming that an actual js-cookie code change will be required.

Comment: i'm using version 3.0.1 and the warning still there :/